# Insert normalized comma-separated field into a new table

Tags: mysql, database

In MySQL I have a `catalog` table like this:

```
id | name  | products |
---|-------|----------|
 5 | name5 |    1,2,3 |
 6 | name6 |      2,3 |
 7 | name7 |        3 |
```

And a `product` table like this:

```
id | name  |
---|-------|
 1 | name1 |
 2 | name2 |
 3 | name3 |
```

Since data retrieving with `FIND_IN_SET` with a join is quite slow I created new table called `catalog_product` (catalog_id, product_id).

Is there a way to **insert the records into the new table** with one query? This is the desired result:

```
catalog_id | catalog_id |
------------------------|
         5 |          1 |
         5 |          2 |
         5 |          3 |
         6 |          2 |
         6 |          3 |
         7 |          3 |
```

MySQL version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: This is my version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` or `LOCATE` can be an alternative to `FIND_IN_SET`, but the test shows that `FIND_IN_SET` will be the fastest.

```
mysql> select benchmark(10000000, FIND_IN_SET(8, '1,8,12,22') > 0);
+------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(10000000, FIND_IN_SET(8, '1,8,12,22') > 0) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    0 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.52 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(10000000, LOCATE(CONCAT(',', 8, ','), CONCAT(',', '1,8,12,22', ',')) > 0);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(10000000, LOCATE(CONCAT(',', 8, ','), CONCAT(',', '1,8,12,22', ',')) > 0) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                   0 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (1.43 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(10000000, CONCAT(',', '1,8,12,22', ',') LIKE (CONCAT('%,', 8, ',%')));
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(10000000, CONCAT(',', '1,8,12,22', ',') LIKE (CONCAT('%,', 8, ',%'))) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                               0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (1.54 sec)
```

So use `FIND_IN_SET` to migrate to a new table:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product (catalog_id, product_id)
SELECT c.id AS catalog_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM product p
JOIN catalog c ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id, c.products) > 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2aad5d3f1445879e3b07c37f5207e777)

Comment: Very detailed answer, it worked perfectly! The analysis is interesting too! Does it matter if I start from catalog join product instead of product join catalog? Is there also a way to run the insert in "multiple batches" insted of one single run? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For 5.7, you can do this (I have a table of integers (i) from with values from 0-9):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_bad_table;

CREATE TABLE my_bad_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,products VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_bad_table VALUES
(5,'name5','1,2,3'),
(6,'name6','2,3'),
(7,'name7','3');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_good_table;

CREATE TABLE my_good_table AS 
SELECT DISTINCT id catalog_id
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products,',',i+1),',',-1)+0 product_id
           FROM my_bad_table
              , ints;

ALTER TABLE my_good_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(catalog_id,product_id);

SELECT * FROM my_good_table;
+------------+------------+
| catalog_id | product_id |
+------------+------------+
|          5 |          1 |
|          6 |          2 |
|          7 |          3 |
|          5 |          2 |
|          6 |          3 |
|          5 |          3 |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was more interested in an `INSERT` query just like @user14717238 provided.

Comment: I needed the query to migrate the data to the new table.

Comment: That appears to be precisely what this does ?!?!

Comment: Ohhh, sorry! I missed the `CREATE TABLE AS` before the `SELECT`. I just selected the values, I didn't know this syntax existed. Anyway I already gave you the +1! Thanks again and sorry.